# Get img src and img dimensions from two dimensional array and display in body

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, function, dimensions

I'm trying to get the image source and set dimensions from an two dimensional array

```
var ImgArray=new Array(2)

ImgArray[0][0] = ["http://imgsrc.jpg"]
ImgArray[0][1] = [width="200",height="200"]
ImgArray[1][0] = ["http://imgsrc.jpg"]
ImgArray[1][1] = [width="200",height="200"]
```

,change the dimensions of the source to the new dimensions (200x200)

```
var i=0;
var j=0;

function NextImg(){
    ++i;
    ++j;
    document.getElementById('imageset').width = ImgArray[i][j]
    document.getElementById('imageset').height = ImgArray[i][j]
    document.getElementById('imageset').src = ImgArray[i][j]
}
```

And display the result here

```
<img id="imageset" /> 
<button type="button" onclick="NextImg()">Next image</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open up your dev tools (F12 in most browser) and look at the errors coming up. Once you do so it becomes very obvious that large chunks of your code aren't even valid javascript, and many other parts have big problems as well.

For example, you start assigning values to `ImgArray[0][0]`...but there isn't even an  `ImgArray[0]` yet to assign a `[0]` to. You may have an Array with a length of 2...but of 2 what? Those values are still `undefined`. You would need to set them as being new Arrays themselves before you could start utilizing them as Arrays. Your dev tools would have immediately told you that that was an issue.

And the values you are assigning aren't valid JS in many cases, such as `[width="200",height="200"]`. That's simply not JS.

If you're trying to make an Object with width/height properties it would be `{width:"200", height:"200"}`, and if you're trying make an Array (which your future usage suggests) then it would be `["200", "200"]`, as Array elements don't have property names in that way, they are indexed from 0. So the first one would just be `[0]` and the second one `[1]`.

On top of that, there is no purpose to your `j` variable, or to incrementing it. There is no other incrementing variable needed.

And you're incrementing at the start of the function too, so your first image would be the second (`[1]`) index of the Array. Try starting `i` at -1 in order for 0 to be the first result after incrementing.

A working JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/c0psj611/

And a far better way (using Objects to store associated data) is here: https://jsfiddle.net/2s5x7nL5/

Comment: @lor - no, you're mixing up arrays and simple objects again. You either do an object if you want it to be a property/value pair, which is curly braces: `{propertyname:"propertyvalue"}` or an array if you want indexed values, which is square brackets: `["value at [0]", "value at [1]"]` arrays do not need property names (i.e. no width/height naming in there)

Comment: Ok, so i keep only `["200", "200"]`... 
So the code should look like this...
`var ImgArray=new Array(3)
ImgArray[0] = new Array(2)
ImgArray[0][0] = ["imgsrc.jpg"]
ImgArray[0][1] = ["200","200"]

ImgArray[1] = new Array(2)
ImgArray[1][0] = ["imgsrc.jpg"]
ImgArray[1][1] = ["200","200"]` right?

Comment: Yes, that is working code. However, one of the reasons this is being so troublesome in the first place is that you're just using Arrays incorrectly. Arrays are for lists of data. The root array (ImgArray) works for that, but the values it's holding should be simple objects (data with property/value pairs), not Arrays. That way each value can simply have a property telling the url, width, and height for that image. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/2s5x7nL5/

Comment: Thanks alot!
The jsfiddle helped alot. 
Could you please explain this line?
  `document.getElementById('imageset').width = ImgArray[i][1][0];`

I can't understand the [i][1][0] part very well.

Comment: @lor - `["200", "200"]` is shorthand syntax for creating an Array with 2 values ("200" and "200"). Since you're assigning that to `ImgArray[i][1]` that means it itself is holding yet another Array...so we're now 3 levels deep with Arrays, so `ImgArray[i][1][0]` would bet the first element of that 3rd level Array and `ImgArray[i][1][1]` would be the second.

Comment: @lor - in fact, `new Array()` is almost completely unused by most in javascript because array literals (the `[]` stuff) are not only easier to type but significantly faster in most cases. Even when making an empty Array you typically just use `var foo = [];`

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing both i and j so you only access:

```
ImgArray[0][0] and  ImgArray[1][1]
```

Plus you are not getting the width and the height in this statement

```
document.getElementById('imageset').width = ImgArray[i][j]
document.getElementById('imageset').height = ImgArray[i][j]
```

---

Given this you should do something like

```
var ImgArray = [["http://imgsrc.jpg", 200, 200],["http://imgsrc.jpg", 200, 200]];
```

Then your function would be like:

```
var i=0;

function NextImg(){
   ++i; //or i++;
   document.getElementById('imageset').width = ImgArray[i][0];
   document.getElementById('imageset').height = ImgArray[i][1];
   document.getElementById('imageset').src = ImgArray[i][2];
}
```

You could keep your display like:

```
<img id="imageset" /> 
<button type="button" onclick="NextImg()">Next image</button>
```

Comment: Setting `.width` and `.height` most definitely does change the width and height, since the element in question is an `<img>` element, and it changes the width and height attributes.